# Blink border 3 times (1 second per loop) in css

Tags: css, animation

Hi i am trying to create animation in css

should blink per second and then repeat 3 times.
at the end the border should look regular by default

I tried the following but the border is disappeared by the end.
at the end I need the border color still be the same as the animation color

```css
.alerts-border {
    border: 1px solid;
    animation: blink 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
}

@keyframes blink { 50% { border-color: #ff0000; }  }
```

```html
<div class="alerts-border">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Try specifying `animation-fill-mode` as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: @CBroe . but how keep the red border

Comment: Which setting have you tried?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Now default color is red.
I changed border to #ff0000
and blink color to #fff;

```css
.alerts-border {
    border: 1px #ff0000 solid;
    
    animation: blink 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

@keyframes blink { 50% { border-color:#fff ; }  }
```

```html
<div class="alerts-border" style="height:40px;width:40px">

</div>
```